# AWK: How to number auto-increment?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file.file content is:

```sh
20210126000880000003|3|33.00|20210126|15:30
1|20210126000000000000000000002207|1220210126080109|1000|100000000000000319|100058110000000325|402041000012|402041000012|PT07|621067000000123645|收款方户名|2021-01-26|2021-01-26|10.00|TN|NCS|12|875466

2|20210126000000000000000000002208|1220210126080110|1000|100000000000000319|100058110000000325|402041000012|402041000012|PT06|621067000000123645|收款方户名|2021-01-26|2021-01-26|20.00|TN|NCS|12|875466

3|20210126000000000000000000002209|1220210126080111|1000|100000000000000319|100058110000000325|402041000012|402041000012|PT08|621067000000123645|收款方户名|2021-01-26|2021-01-26|3.00|TN|NCS|12|875466
```

I use awk command:

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==1{print $1};FNR==2{print $2,$3}'  testfile
```

Get the following result：

```
20210126000880000003
20210126000000000000000000002207 1220210126080109
```

I want the number to auto-increase:

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==1{print $1+1};FNR==2{print $2+1,$3+1}' testfile
```

But get follow result:

```
20210126000880001024
20210126000000000944237587726336 1220210126080110
```

have question:

I want to the numer is auto-increase: hope the result is：

```
20210126000880000003
20210126000000000000000000002207|1220210126080109
-------------------------------------------------
20210126000880000004
20210126000000000000000000002208|1220210126080110
--------------------------------------------------
20210126000880000005
20210126000000000000000000002209|1220210126080111
```

How to auto_increase?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want to call awk multiple times on an input file and each time you call it show the values of $1 from line 1 and $2 from line 2 but with their values incrementing by 1 every time you call awk? Or are you saying something else? Please [edit] your question to clarify. Also tell us if there's any significance to there being about a dozen `0`s` in the middle of each number you're interested in (e.g. it's really 2 different numbers with `0`s padding in between).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `gnu awk` command:

```sh
awk -M 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} NR == 1 {hdr = $1; next} NF>2 {print ++hdr; print $2, $3; print "-------------------"}' file

20210126000880000004
20210126000000000000000000002207|1220210126080109
-------------------
20210126000880000005
20210126000000000000000000002208|1220210126080110
-------------------
20210126000880000006
20210126000000000000000000002209|1220210126080111
-------------------
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk -M 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="|"
}
NR == 1 {
   hdr = $1
   next
}
NF > 2 {
   print ++hdr
   print $2, $3
   print "-------------------"
}' file
```

---

Here is a POSIX awk solution that doesn't need `-M`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} NR == 1 {hdr = $1; next} NF>2 {"echo " hdr " + 1 | bc" | getline hdr; print hdr; print $2, $3; print "-------------------"}' file

20210126000880000004
20210126000000000000000000002207|1220210126080109
-------------------
20210126000880000005
20210126000000000000000000002208|1220210126080110
-------------------
20210126000880000006
20210126000000000000000000002209|1220210126080111
-------------------
```

Comment: I had more or less exactly the same solution but weirdly on GNU awk 4.0.2, the count header goes from 20210126000880000003 to 20210126000880001024 and doesn't change. What version of awk are you using?

Comment: @RamanSailopal: I have `GNU Awk 5.1.0`. Make sure to use `-M` switch as suggested in answer.

Comment: Ah. -M isn't available on 4.0.2. I've just checked and it is for "big numbers" That's probably why it doesn't work on older versions. Thanks.

Comment: @RamanSailopal FYI you also need a version of gawk that was specifically built with this functionality in mind for `-M` to work so you can't assume it'll work on all installations of even the most recent gawk.

Comment: @anubhava  I build and upgrade  awk5.1, but run awk command  get warning:  -M ignored: MPFR/GMP support not compiled in .........

Comment: That just means awk binary wasn't compiled with `-M` support.

Comment: See my updated answer for a POSIX solution

Answer (score 1):

Anubhava has the best solution but for older versions of GNU awk that don't support -M (big numbers) you can try the following:

```
awk -F\| 'NR==1 { print $1;hed=$1;hed1=substr($1,(length($1)-1));next; } !/^$/ {print $2" "$3 } /^$/ { print "--------------------------------------------------";printf "%s%s\n",substr(hed,1,((length(hed))-(length(hed1)+1))),++hed1 }' testfile
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F\| 'NR==1 {                                                   # Set field delimiter to | and process the first line
                   print $1;                                        # Print the first field
                   hed=$1;                                          # Set the variable hed to the first field
                   hed1=substr($1,(length($1)-1));                  # Set a counter variable hed1 to the last digit in hed ($1)
                   next; 
                 } 
           !/^$/ {
                   print $2" "$3                                     # Where there is no blank line, print the second field, a space and the third field
                 } 
            /^$/ { 
                   print "--------------------------------------------------";     # Where there is a blank field, process
                   printf "%s%s\n",substr(hed,1,((length(hed))-(length(hed1)+1))),++hed1                                                # print the header extract before the counter, followed by the incremented counter
                  }' testfile
```

Comment: But this solution is not going to work even on any AWK. Test it when `$1` is `20210126000889999999`, you will see the problem.